# Как реализовать плавное перемещение курсора мыши на С#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, gui, библиотеки

Как можно реализовать **плавное перемещение курсора мыши** к какой-либо точке на экране на языке C# в среде Microsoft Visual Studio?

Comment: В смысле "плавное"? "Точка" - это брейкпоинт или любое место? Обычно для навигации по предыдущей, текущей позиции используют шоткаты `ctrl и +` и `ctrl и -` (или клавишами мыши вперёд-назад). Между брейкпоинтами насколько я знаю переходить шоткатами нельзя (если не считать, собственно, F10, F11, SHift+F11)

Comment: Вы имеете в виду курсор мыши или текстовый курсор?

Comment: Я имею в виду курсор мыши. У меня программа кликает на кнопки на сайте, но курсор мгновенно перемещается, а я хочу чтобы плавно, чтобы было будто человек это делает.

Comment: @J.Do: Если программа кликает на кнопки, вы пользуетесь каким-то фреймворком для этого?

Comment: GRUNGER, не пойму о чем ты, но думаю что любое место на экране. И думаю, что это не то)

Comment: using WindowsInput; и все.

Comment: @J.Do: А что такое `WindowsInput`? У вас точно нет опечаток? Окей, зайдём с другой стороны: какой тип проекта вы создали? Что у вас в References?

Comment: Из добавленного личной мной ничего.

Comment: @J.Do: Но всё же. Поскольку вы не говорите, какой тип проекта вы создали, непонятно, что у вас там по умолчанию.

Comment: Приложение Windows Form c#

Comment: Я вроде как понял, что вам нужно - плавная "эмуляция" движения руки человека? Данной готовой реализации нет и, конечно, искать чудесный метод в .NET тоже не имеет смысла. Данная задача требует знания по дискретной математике, как минимум. Если речь идёт о действительно "плавной" эмуляции. Если проще - можно накидать нейросеть и научить её за пару вечеров вашим движениям. И потом использовать. Ещё проще - только в цикле с синусами\косинусами рисовать между двумя несколькими окружностями (к примеру) и вести курсор по полученной диагонали. Ещё проще - `for` но это нельзя называть эмуляцией :)

Comment: GRUNGER, понял, спасибо. Просто допустим в Unity на том же C#, я мог в функции, которая выполняется каждый кадр, за каждое выполнение по немногу увеличивать координаты. Это выглядело бы достаточно плавно. Что-нибудь такое можно в visual studio реализовать? (я понимаю, что программы абсолютно разные и т.д., но может здесь есть что-нибудь похожее)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плавное перемещение можно реализовать по таймеру.

Например, в приложении Windows Forms. Или в приложении любого другого типа, но при этом нужно в `References` проекта добавить ссылку на библиотеку `System.Windows.Forms.dll`. Это нужно, чтобы можно было обращаться к свойству `Position` класса `Cursor`.

В коде пишем:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;


// Поле класса
System.Threading.Timer timer;


// Создаём и запускаем таймер с интервалом 10 миллисекунд
timer = new System.Threading.Timer(CursorMove, null, 0, 10);

// Метод, вызываемый таймером. Перемещает курсор
private void CursorMove(object state)
{
    var point = Cursor.Position;
    point.X++;
    Cursor.Position = point;
}
```

Когда таймер нужно остановить, вызываем

```
timer.Dispose();
```